# Device information on com port c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, hardware

I had such a problem: in the three com ports have devices with which I work in software. Not installed drivers. The problem is: How can I find out which of the ports is connected with which of device? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to identify the devices in the COM ports.  There is no industry standard nor requirement for device names.  Some protocols such as SCSI, ATAPI and USB have commands that you can use to identify the device.  For standard RS232, there is no such requirement.

What kind of devices do you have to identify?  Plotters, thumbdrives, tape drives, etc?

Comment: Some modems have commands for returning their identification.  I have no clue about how to identify a bill acceptor dispenser.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to do this. You can poll the COM ports, but many devices don't even respond to commands they receive. A COM port could only have Tx and Gnd wired up, so the connected device might not even be able to respond. You have very little to work with when dealing with RS232.